# How can I contruct a `X?` concrete syntax value?

Tags: rascal, concrete-syntax-tree

I have this concrete syntax:

```
syntax SomeMore = [...] SyncBlock? sync;
syntax SyncBlock = "sync" "{" SyncStatement* stats "}";
syntax SyncStatement = [...];
```

`[SyncBlock]"sync { <syncStrings> }"` seems to work, but when I try to use it as a `SyncBlock?` and assign it:

```
SyncBlock? sync = [SyncBlock?]"sync { <syncStrings> }"
```

it does not work: `inline parsing not supported on SyncBlock?`, what is the easiest way to build up a value of this `X?`-type?

Can I convert a `SyncBlock` to a `SyncBlock?` somehow?

Something like this also doesn’t work:
`` syncBlock = (SyncBlock?)`sync { <SyncStatement* syncs>}`; ``

P.S. `SyncBlock? syncBlock = …` results in `Ambiguous code (internal error), SyncBlock? syncBlock = …`. Probably due to a ternary operator ambiguity?

Comment: Same problem seems to happen for `X*` syntax elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, not ideal, but it works.
It seems that the `?` in the types introduces some difficulties, but can be circumvented using an "alias" for this type:

I changed the grammar to:

```
syntax SomeMore = [...] MaybeSyncBlock sync;
syntax MaybeSyncBlock = SyncBlock?;
syntax SyncBlock = "sync" "{" SyncStatement* stats "}";
syntax SyncStatement = [...];
```

Now this works:

```
MaybeSyncBlock syncBlock = [MaybeSyncBlock]"sync { <syncStrings> }";
```

Comment: it's a known issue. we're planning for a general solution.